# Reference request: "Inheritance" from free term to solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am working on problems that deal with "inheritance" from free terms to solutions of differential equations.

Let me give an example:
Consider the ODE
$$
f'(t) = f(t) + g(t), \qquad t \ge 0,
$$
where $g$ is some real-valued function.
I am interested in questions of the following type:

> If $g$ is differentiable/smooth/convex/etc., what can I say about $f$?

This ODE is so simple that it can be solved explicitly, but I do not want to do that. Instead, I want to deduce something about $f$ by simply looking at the ODE. For example:

- Suppose $g$ is continuously differentiable. Then $f' = f + g$ is continuously differentiable as well, hence $f$ must be twice continuously differentiable.
- Suppose $g \ge 0.$ If there is a $t > 0$ such that $f(t) = 0,$ then $f'(t) = g(t) \ge 0.$ Hence $f \ge 0$.
- Suppose $g$ is convex. Is $f$ convex as well?

This kind of "inheritance" seems interesting to me; questions of this type can be applied to ODEs, PDEs, integral equations, etc.
Do you know any results that fall into this category? Is there a technical term for results of this type?

Comment: How exactly are you planning to do that without information about $f$?

Comment: I view the differential equation as an implicit characterization of $f$. Of course existence (and uniqueness, given some boundary condition) of a solution must be established separately.

Comment: Well, there is the entire subject of regularity theory of PDEs (a massive topic), but that is only going to give you results of the kind in your first bullet. I think in the class you're looking at (linear DEs where the function you're "inheriting" from is the forcing), your questions boil down to analyzing the Green's function (whether it can be explicitly furnished or not).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that! The ODE was just a simple example, I am mostly interested in integral equations ... but I would like to get an overview if similar things have been done for differential equations or related objects